# Parsing coverFlow images through web service

Tags: iphone, xml-parsing

I have implemented coverFlow usinng http://chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m this link. Its working fine. I want to get coverFlow images through web service. Its working fine for single image. Anyone send me code for getting  multiple coverFlow images in a single url having multiple image attributes.Any changes in backend should reflect in code means if no of images are increased then in coverflow also show the same no. of images.

Answer (score 0):

In CoverFlowViewController.h file

```
NSMutableArray *profilephotos;    // declare NSMutableArray
```

In CoverFlowViewController.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    profilephotos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"www.xxxx.com/ima.jpeg",@"www.xxxx.com/ima1.jpeg",@"www.xxxx.com/ima2.jpeg",@"www.xxxx.com/ima3.jpeg",@"www.xxxx.com/ima4.jpeg",@"www.yyy.com/ima5.jpeg",nil];
    NSLog(@"profilephotos = %@",profilephotos);  // Your array of Images url
    loadImagesOperationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i < [profilephotos count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *pho = [profilephotos objectAtIndex:i];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:pho];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
        UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

        CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(300.0f, 300.0f);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
        [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        [(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setImage:newImage forIndex:i];
    }
    [(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setNumberOfImages:[profilephotos count]];
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. i need code for singl url having multiple image tag

Comment: How you are receiving images? show your received image url link or code.

Comment: - (UIImage *)flowCover:(FlowCoverView *)view cover:(int)image
{
    
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://abilcms.com.sv2.premiumwebserver.com/WebServiceElevation.aspx?ProjectName=Castle Royale Grande"]; 
    
    //NSData *data1=[NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString];
    
    
    
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    
    return [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    
}